# How to add text at the end of each line in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, ksh

I am doing certain text processing operations and finally able to get a file something like this

```
india
sudan
japan
france
```

now I want to add a comment in the above file like in the final file it should be something like

```
india | COUNTRY
sudan | COUNTRY
japan | COUNTRY
france | COUNTRY
```

like a same comment across the whole file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

There are many ways:

`sed`: replace `$` (end of line) with the given text.

```
$ sed 's/$/ | COUNTRY/' file
india | COUNTRY
sudan | COUNTRY
japan | COUNTRY
france | COUNTRY
```

`awk`: print the line plus the given text.

```
$ awk '{print $0, "| COUNTRY"}' file
india | COUNTRY
sudan | COUNTRY
japan | COUNTRY
france | COUNTRY
```

Finally, in pure `bash`: read line by line and print it together with the given text. Note this is discouraged as explained in [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/40596)

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do echo "$line | COUNTRY"; done < file
india | COUNTRY
sudan | COUNTRY
japan | COUNTRY
france | COUNTRY
```

Comment: All the solutions work, assuming the lines end with a line feed ("\n").
I had a file coming from Windows with carriage return and line feed ("\r\n"), and I got the desired comment at the beginning of the line . I just converted the file with dos2unix and all the solutions work fine.

Comment: MacOS only uses Carriage Return (`\r`), hence, you have to write `sed 's/\r/ | COUNTRY/' file` there.

Answer (score 5):

Another `awk`

```
awk '$0=$0" | COUNTRY"' file
```

Comment: I thought of this too, this might be the shortest awk solution... +1

Comment: Just for fun, I compared the performance with a 20M lines file. `time awk '{print $0, "| COUNTRY"' a &>/dev/null` takes around 0.003s, while `time awk '$0=$0" | COUNTRY"' a &>/dev/null` around 4.03s. I guess the assignment consumes way more extra time.

Comment: @fedorqui Interesting.  Shortness is not always the best :)

Comment: @Jotne indeed, I did not expect such result. But of course, it is an edge case and your answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: I don't get this running properly... I get the | COUNTRY at the beginning of the line... Why is that?

Comment: Are you using a MacOS computer?  In that case, you have to use `\r` instead of `$`.  At least, it did for me the trick.

Answer (score 4):

For a more obfuscated approach:

```
yes '| COUNTRY' | sed $(wc -l < file)q | paste -d ' ' file -
```

Comment: On a side note, in my tests the `paste` tool is really fast, even for big (>20MB) test files.

Comment: @00prometheus: Without the `-d` option, `paste` joins using a tab character by default. You could move the space to be before the `|`, but you'd still need `-d ''` to suppress the tab.

Comment: You are right. I removed my comment to avoid misleading anyone.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `xargs` with `echo` for this:

```
< file xargs -d "\n" -rI % echo '% | COUNTRY'
```

This will make `xargs` take each line of `file` and pass it one at a time† to the specified `echo` command, replacing the `%` (or whatever character you choose) with the input line.

† By default `xargs` will pass multiple lines of input to a single command, appending them all to its argument list. But specifying `-I %` makes `xargs` put the input at the specified place in the command, and only put one line there at a time, running `echo` as many times as required.